# Delphi 2009 - Handle when window is restored via double clicking the SysMenu?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, devexpress, vcl, window-messages

I need to handle when the user restores the form by double clicking the title bar. I tried handling the WM_SYSCOMMAND window message however this only works if the user restores the form via clicking the restore button in the system menu.

I am using DevExpress ribbon form components if this matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean double-clicking on the title bar because double clicking on the system menu closes the form.
WM_SYSCOMMAND should work since the sequence of messages when double-clicking on the title bar to restore the form is:

```
Message posted: hwnd=$004E0820 WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK wParam $00000002 lParam $000705D4 Process Project1.exe (2380)
=> Message sent: hwnd=$004E0820 WM_SYSCOMMAND restore cmd requested (-44,-44) Process Project1.exe (2380)
Message sent: hwnd=$004E0820 WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING wParam $00000000 lParam $0012F4CC Process Project1.exe (2380)
Message sent: hwnd=$004E0820 WM_GETMINMAXINFO wParam $00000000 lParam $0012EF6C Process Project1.exe (2380)
Message sent: hwnd=$004E0820 WM_NCCALCSIZE wParam $00000001 lParam $0012F4A0 Process Project1.exe (2380)
Message sent: hwnd=$004E0820 WM_NCPAINT update region  40040F4B Process Project1.exe (2380)
Message sent: hwnd=$004E0820 WM_ERASEBKGND wParam $31011DCA lParam $00000000 Process Project1.exe (2380)
Message sent: hwnd=$004E0820 WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED wParam $00000000 lParam $0012F4CC Process Project1.exe (2380)
```

The problem is that the **CmdType const SC_RESTORE2** = 61730 //0xF122 is **missing** in Windows.pas.

See the working code below:

```
type
  TForm7 = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
  end;

var
  Form7: TForm7;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm7 }

const
  SC_RESTORE2 = 61730; //0xF122

procedure TForm7.WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand);
begin
  case Message.CmdType of
    SC_RESTORE2 : beep;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

**Update**: reference to `SC_RESTORE2` from [**WM_SYSCOMMAND** Notification on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360%28VS.85%29.aspx) (see the "values in C#" part)

Comment: Missing from Windows.pas? It's evidently missing from WinUser.h, too. Where is that flag named and documented?

Comment: For anyone not bothered to follow the links:  SC_RESTORE is sent when restored from the TaskBar.  SC_RESTORE2 has a different value and is specifically sent when restoring by double-clicking the caption bar.

This looks to me as if SC_RESTORE2 is a more recently introduced notification, and it may not be supported on all Windows versions.  The general documentation on the topic does not mention SC_RESTORE2 at all, nor does it indicate what Windows versions may or may not support it.

Comment: @Deltics, I tested this in Windows XP (x32), Vista (x32/x64), 7 and it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone finds this later in a search...

The problem isn't with anything missing from Windows.pas, because SC_RESTORE2 is not supposed to be there.  As noted by Rob Kennedy, the SC_RESTORE2 value isn't in WinUser.h either.  The problem is that François' sample code (and presumably James' code) fails to bitwise-and the wParam (Message.CmdType) with $FFF0.  This is described in the updated link from François, and also noted in the "Values in C#" community content, where it even says *not* to use SC_RESTORE2.  Note that SC_RESTORE2 and $FFF0 = SC_RESTORE.

Comment: can you state what the lower byte contains?